# RESTful API with HOBA authentication in OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to create a specification of an HTTP RESTful API in OpenAPI.
Since authorization and authentication are strict requirements and I don't have HTTPS security, it seems to me that the only available HTTP authentication scheme is HOBA (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7486).
How do I describe HOBA with Swagger editor or e.g., Stoplight Studio or similar editor?